# Change the cursor if hovered over a particular region of a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a custom widget in which I have drawn a small triangle. I would like to know whether I can change my cursor if hover over the triangle I have drawn over the widget.

Note: I have tried to use `mouseMoveEvent` but it doesn't update unless clicked. I have also tried to `eventFilter` but it looks like it doesn't even enter that method.

Here is a similar code not the same. The triangle is at the bottom. I want the cursor to automatically update when it's over the red triangle

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QPointF, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QIcon, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys


class Stack(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Stack, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cursor_x = [x for x in range(self.width() - 20, self.width())]
        self.cursor_y = [y for y in range(self.height() - 20, self.height())]


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        
        super(Stack, self).paintEvent(event)
        qp = QPainter(self)
    
        qp.setPen(Qt.white)

        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        qp.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 150)

        p = QPointF(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPointF(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPointF(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPolygon(p, q, r)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            if event.x() in self.cursor_x and event.y() in self.cursor_y:
                print('yes')
                self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.x() in self.cursor_x and event.y() in self.cursor_y:

            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        super(Stack, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print(event)
        print('hello')
        if obj is self and event.type() == QEvent.HoverEnter:
            print("Mouse is over the label")

        super().eventFilter(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.x() not in self.cursor_x and event.y() not in self.cursor_y:
            self.unsetCursor()
            super(Stack, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Stack()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please show your attempt, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc is it ok if I just show the `mouseMoveEvent ` and `eventFilter` methods?

Comment: If you indicate that you have tried something then you must show it through an MRE, because if you don't do it it is as you would not have tried, and one of the basic principles in SO is that the OPs show their effort in solving their problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc added sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to deactivate the cursor also when it is outside the region. For the mouseMoveEvent you must enable the mouseTracking property. And finally I use a QPolygon to check if the cursor is inside or outside the rectangle:

```
class Stack(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Stack, self).__init__(parent)
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def _recalculate_triangle(self):
        p = QPoint(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)
        self._triangle = QPolygon([p, q, r])
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._recalculate_triangle()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Stack, self).paintEvent(event)
        qp = QPainter(self)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)

        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        qp.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 150)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPolygon(self._triangle)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
            event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
        ):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        else:
            self.unsetCursor()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        else:
            self.unsetCursor()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
            event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
        ):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        else:
            self.unsetCursor()
```